# Old image still showing in TableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uitableview

I can't understand why my TableView is still showing the old image I used despite I remove it from my code and group file...Any idea why ? I already made "Reset" in ios simulator and I saw no changes.

Stephane

Comment: How are you showing the image? Is it set in IB, loaded into a UIImageView, set as a background property, loaded as a "colorWithPatternImage", or some other method?

Comment: through a NIB file, but the UIImageView in the NIB is blank

Comment: I used this old image in first test and it's still showing up even when I update the image view

Comment: Without seeing any code it's difficult to say what the problem is. Are you loading the image programmatically somewhere else? Have you tried cleaning the build and deleting the app from the simulator?

Comment: What I made is just subclassing UITableViewCell then I associated a NIB (with related UITableViewCell controller). In the subclass I added an image view for left imageview, and 3 labels. The imageview and labels are then connected to their respective properties in the subclass to allow content setting from TableView datasource methods.

Comment: Then are you setting the image in one of the datasource methods?

Comment: Then the app's successfully updating all 3 labels but when it comes to imageview the old one is still showing. I removed the app from simulator and reset the ios simulator. How to cleaning the build ?

Comment: It sounds like you're just not setting the image properly in the code. You should edit your post and add at least part of your code to your post. You can clean by going to Product->Clean in the menu (Xcode 4).

Comment: I think Evan is right here - I've found that a clean is necessary when dealing with deleted/removed resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a "Clean" (Command+Shift+K) on your project, then build again. Without Cleaning, deleted or replaced files can stay in your build directory and keep showing up. This has happened to me in the past.

If that doesn't resolve the issue, try Cleaning, then deleting the app from the Simulator, then quitting then Simulator, THEN building again.

If THAT doesn't resolve the issue I may need to see more code to help.